# OpenSSL used fixed Values for Diffie Hellman Key generation

Tags: c, openssl, diffie-hellman

According to that piece of documentation: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Diffie_Hellman#Using_the_Low_Level_APIs

Using the Low level API's for Diffie Hellman (need to perform a group Key agreement).

For simplicity I need to provide fixed values for Diffie Hellman `p` and `g` values for now I use the function `DH_generate_parameters_ex` but any solution using these options may add a communication overhead and there are fixed values for `p` and `g` for Diffie Hellman offering good security.

So using the approach convention over configuration, how I can set fixed values especially the ones specified in this [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3526) to openssl low-level api fore diffie hellman instyead of generating ones on the fly?

PS I use the OpenSSL version 1.0.2g.

Answer (score 2):

The (outer) *primes* for the RFC3526 and RFC2409 groups are builtin, per [this man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/DH_get_1024_160.html) (should also be on your system under those names if 1.1.0+) -- they are actually in the code back to before 1.0.0 but without the `BN_` prefix (though in the `bn.h` header) and previously undocumented. (In 1.1.0+ the old names are additionally #define'd if compatibility is set.)

AFAICS you must add the generator yourself, something like:

```
DH *dh = DH_new(); BIGNUM *two = BN_new(); 
if( !dh || !two ) /* error */;
BN_set_word(two,2); 

// corrected AGAIN!
DH_set0_pqg (dh, BN_dup(BN_get_rfc3526_prime_2048(NULL)), NULL, two);

// added: below 1.1.0 many API structs were not opaque, just
dh->p = BN_dup(/*not BN_*/ get_rfc3526_prime_2048(NULL));
dh->g = two; 
// leave q as unspecified
```

Note RFC5114 modp parameters are available prebuilt in `DH*` form but only in 1.1.0+.

Comment: Should I replace your piece of code with the `DH_generate_parameters_ex` function? Or Should I live it and place the code afterwards?

Comment: Furthermore In my case I have the 1.0.2g version of OPENSSL thus the `DH_set0_pgq` is not defined is there an alternative one?

Comment: This snippet of code throws the following error: `dh.c:21:38: error: too few arguments to function ‘BN_get_rfc3526_prime_2048’` The spec nees to offer a BIGNUM as a parameter.

Comment: Do I need to perfom any further checks like the `DH_check` ones as seen in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54559829/4706711)?

Comment: If you trust the people who published the RFC are benign and competent you don't need to check. Why DH_check is failing will take time to look at, but if I can I'll answer or comment on your new Q.

Comment: In my case there is no method `DH_set0_pgq` and I get the error: `dh.c:17:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘DH_set0_pgq’; did you mean ‘DH_set0_pqg’? `

Comment: Yes; fixed. Sorry.